# PyQt5 Paint Circle Over Video in QLabel

Tags: python, video, pyqt, qpainter, qlabel

I want to draw a circle that displays over a video at the cursor location when pressing the mouse.  The video is playing in a QLabel object that is in a MainWindow.  I’m using OpenCV to read frames from the webcam at 10 fps.  I’m converting the frames to QPixmap and displaying them in the QLabel object (`self.vidWindow`).

In the code below, the circle is painted immediately when the MainWindow is launched (not what I want) and is then covered up by the video stream.  Text displays in the mask Qlabel object and a message is printed in the MainWindow when the mouse button is pressed.

Can I draw a circle in a QLabel object?  If so, should I use the mask QLabel object or is there a way to overlay directly over the video in the `self.vidWindow`?

In the minimalized version of the code, the video displays, but an error is triggered when I try to draw the ellipse.

```
import sys, cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, QCoreApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.initUI()        

    def initUI(self):                       
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')        
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Statusbar')
        self.vidWindow = QLabel(self)
        self.vidWindow.setGeometry(20, 20, 640, 480)
        self.maskWindow = QLabel(self)
        self.maskWindow.setGeometry(20, 20, 640, 480)
        self.maskWindow.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0%)')
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.maskWindow.setFont(font)
        self.maskWindow.setText('Message is on the mask Qlabel object')
        self.msgLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(675, 300, 100, 20)
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.pix = QImage()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.frame_rate = 5
        self.show()
        self.start()

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = QImage(frame,frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            img = img.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            self.vidWindow.setPixmap(self.pix)

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):        
        self.msgLabel.setText('Mouse Clicked!')

    def paintEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        e = QMouseEvent
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green,  4, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(e.x(), e.y(), 100)

    def start(self):
        rate = int(1000.0 / self.frame_rate)        
        self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(rate)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            self.cap.release()
            self.vidWindow.clear()        
        QCoreApplication.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although QPainter is used to paint a widget it will not work for this case since it paints the "MainWindow" that is below its children as the QLabels. There are at least 2 possible solutions:

- Create a custom QLabel and detect the click and paint the circle,
- Create a QLabel that shows a QPixmap that has the circle and move it based on the mouse information.

In this case I will implement the second method:

```py
import sys, cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Statusbar")
        self.vidWindow = QLabel(self)
        self.vidWindow.setGeometry(20, 20, 640, 480)
        self.maskWindow = QLabel(self)
        self.maskWindow.setGeometry(20, 20, 640, 480)
        self.maskWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0%)")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.maskWindow.setFont(font)
        self.maskWindow.setText("Message is on the mask Qlabel object")
        self.msgLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(675, 300, 100, 20)

        self.marker_label = QLabel(self)

        pixmap = QPixmap(100, 100)
        pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)

        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 4, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(pixmap.rect().adjusted(4, 4, -4, -4))
        painter.end()

        self.marker_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.marker_label.adjustSize()
        self.marker_label.hide()
        self.marker_label.raise_()

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.frame_rate = 5
        self.show()
        self.start()

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            img = img.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            self.vidWindow.setPixmap(pix)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.msgLabel.setText("Mouse Clicked!")
        if self.vidWindow.rect().contains(event.pos()):
            self.marker_label.move(event.pos() - self.marker_label.rect().center())
            self.marker_label.show()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def start(self):
        rate = int(1000.0 / self.frame_rate)
        self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(rate)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.cap.isOpened():
            self.cap.release()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works great!  I agree with @s-nick that the custom QLabel would be interesting to see but I think this solution is probably easier to implement and works perfectly fine.